# Laravel 4 Many to Many with Eloquent and checkboxes

Tags: database, laravel, many-to-many, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to fix a problem with my Application using Laravel 4. The problem is about Eloquent and M:M relationship.

Here's my situation:
I've many users that can choose many services, for each service they can provide a dedicated price. In the database I've tables named "services","users" and "users_services".
So at the moment I can save the services and the prices that every user choose BUT my problem is that I don't know how to retrive and show them to the user, I mean I don't know how to set up "checked" to the checkboxes of every selected service and the price for each one too.

You can check the code here [on Paste Laravel](http://paste.laravel.com/Q3V) for any fork. I paste it here too.

```
    <?php

class Service extends Eloquent {

    public static $rules = array();

    protected $guarded = array('id');

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'services';

    /**
     * -------------------------------------
     * All Joins w/ other tables
     * -------------------------------------
     **/
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User','users_services','services_id','user_id');
    }
}

......

<?php

class User extends Eloquent {

    public static $rules = array();

    protected $guarded = array('id');

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * -------------------------------------
     * All Joins w/ other tables
     * -------------------------------------
     **/
    public function services()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('Service','users_services','user_id','service_id');
        }       
}

................

// Inside the controller 

$services = Service::all();
$this->layout->content = View::make('private.user.services')->with(compact('services'));

...............

// The view
@foreach($services as $service)
 <div class="pull-left col-lg-6 service-container">
  <div class="checkbox pull-left">
   <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="{{ $service->id }}"><span>{{ $service->name }}</span>
   </label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group service-price pull-right">
  <input type="number" min="0" name="prices[{{$service->id}}]" class="form-control pull-rigth" placeholder="0">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" disabled><i class="icon-eur"></i></button>
   </span>
  </div>
 </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Are you showing all services on the page, and you want to check the checkboxs of those that the current user has chosen?  Or, are you going to display on the page only the services that were chosen by the current user?

Comment: @msturdy I'will show all services and I wanto to check the checkboxes for the chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work for you

1) in controller, store the list of services related to some user (the currently logged in user?) and than pass them to the view

```
 // ... get some $user
 $some_users_services = $user->related()->lists('service_id');
 // ... view make stuff etc.
```

2) in your view, while generating the checkbox list, check if it matches the user's chosen services (related services ids)

```
 @if( in_array($service->id, $some_users_services) ) checked="checked" @endif
```

hope this helps you out

Comment: Auth::user() is the logged user who handle the "users", just like an administrator.

Comment: ah I see, so you need to change this Auth::user() to an instance of any other user you want to verify services against. I mean that if you want to check services of user with some id , change it to User::find($id_of_the_user_u_want). I edited my answer to include your comment

Comment: The only problem now is to setup the price for the selected service :S

Comment: what do you mean by "set up the price", you want to print out the service price as the input default value ?

Answer (score 5):

In your view, as you're looping through all possible services, you need to check if the current user has that service selected.

One way would be to send a second collection to the page, of the user's services, then use the [`contains()`](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections) method to check it.

**In your Controller** pull the services from the User's relationship into a new variable:

```
$services      = Service::all();
$user_services = $user->services;
$this->layout->content = View::make('private.user.services')->with(compact('services'))->with('user_services', $user_services);
```

**In your view** just add the checked attr to the checkbox..

```
@foreach($services as $service)
 <div class="pull-left col-lg-6 service-container">
  <div class="checkbox pull-left">
   <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="{{ $service->id }}" @if( $user_services->contains($service->id) ) selected@endif><span>{{ $service->name }}</span>
   </label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group service-price pull-right">
  <input type="number" min="0" name="prices[{{$service->id}}]" class="form-control pull-rigth" placeholder="0">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" disabled><i class="icon-eur"></i></button>
   </span>
  </div>
 </div>
@endforeach
```

Note, it's not tested, and I don't know the relationships you have between the models.. but it should be ok :)

*(note, you have a typo in one of your classes.. `pull-rigth`)*

Comment: IT works!! The only problem now is to setup the price for the selected service :S

Comment: hehe, buona fortuna!  :)

Answer (score 0):

msturdy's answer is quite nice, but for checkboxes, I would put "checked" instead of "selected". Other than that, it works great. Thanks!